# Rails Controller -- just return the processed data (dont load into a view)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

I'm new to Ruby and Rails. I just completed a  course in Laravel, so I am aware of the MVC system(not a newbie as far as the basic concepts are concerned).

I have a rather simple question,

I am sending a POST request to my RAILS REST API,the body of the post request contains a json encoded string like this--->

```
 Array ( [method] => POST [timeout] => 45 [redirection] => 5 [httpversion] => 1.0 [blocking] => 1 [headers] => Array ( ) [body] => {"post_content":"here is the post","post_title":"here we are ","post_author":"1"} [cookies] => Array ( ) )
```

As you can see,its coming from my php based blog.
My rails API is supposed to be taking the post content and automatically adding links to certains words, by comparing the words with some stuff that i have in an SQLite database.

Ok, so my problem is this:
  I just want the response from the Rails controller, I dont want anything loaded into a view. The Rails Controller - returns the content, with 'a href' tags around words that are found in my database. This is to be sent back as the response to my post request, and i want to access it directly as the body of the response.
As of now I dont know how this is to be done. Laravel has the ability to 'return' whatever you want to , at the end of the Controller Action, but in Rails, everything seems to want to load into a view.
I have researched some questions here and found one which said 'render :nothing => true',but that renders nothing at all.Here is what my code looks like.

```
def process
content = params['post_content']
##perform db function and get back the content with the links embedded.
##HOW TO RETURN THIS CONTENT. 
end
```

Personally, I think, i have to use the render_to_string method, but I have no idea how to do this.

Any help is appreciated.
Best Regards,
Richard Madson.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some options to consider:

Render just the raw string as the http response body:

```
render :text => content
```

Render a view without the default surrounding layout:

```
render :layout => false
```

In that case your view could just be:

```
<%= @content %>
```

Or render the content as json:

```
render :json => { :content => content }
```

Answer (score 1):

The question is, what do you want returned? Text? XML? JSON?

I'm going to assume you want JSON back based on the JSON going in.

```
respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render json: @someobject }
end
```

It might be helpful to see the rest of the controller method.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly believe what you are looking for is

```
render :text => "response"
```

there is also - JSON, XML, nothing, js, file, etc - more information here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html